# Ms access sub report keeps overlapping, why?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I have an access database with a report that contains several subreport. the problem is that the subreport keeps overlapping. I have used the `Can Grow = Yes` on all report and nothing works. however, when I'm in print preview the report loads fine but report view is where I'm having the problem. what can i do to fix this? thanks

PS. im using access 2007 and the database format is .mdb

Comment: There are properties on the actual sections of reports, also. Ensure those are set to `CanGrow = Yes`. Have you tried [this method](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/930785-subreports-overlapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer on Microsoft's Website. I needed to install `Office 2007 suite Service Pack 2` they have an excel sheet with all the changes under the section `Downloadable list of issues that the service pack fixes` on [this page.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953195) :)